# Charging a USB device with ac connection

Tags: usb

I have a device that charges via a USB connection. Can you also connect that USB cord to AC adapter and charge it safely?

Comment: It would be nice if you could clarify what the devices you mention are. "AC adapter" is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If your adapter outputs 5v **DC** then yes, but in that case it's a bit more than a physical adapter. Under no circumstances can a USB device be connected to an AC source without first converting the AC source to DC and regulating the voltage to 5v (assuming USB 2.0/3.0 -- USB C and the 3.1/3.2 standards allow for higher voltage if proper components are on both sides. )